# Get all connected device name on the network - Python

Tags: python, network-programming, raspberry-pi

I try to get all connected device name and IP on my network.

I've a raspberry pi and I want to use it as a "Network supervisor". For example if a new device is connected I want to display its IP and name.

I tried some libraries like nmap and scapy but isn't really what I try to do.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the nmap data into python by using subprocess

```
import subprocess
nmap = subprocess.Popen('nmap', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
ipout = nmap.communicate()[0]
```

from there you can use basic python to strip down what you have in ipout and check if there are any differences and if so state those differences.

Answer (score 0):

Typo @ Scott's answer, ...stdout**=**subprocess.PIPE). I dont have the rep to just comment.

```
import subprocess
nmap = subprocess.Popen(('nmap'), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
ipout = nmap.communicate()[
```

Comment: Fixed it. You might decide to keep or not keep your answer.